# retrieve records where aggregate function is subject to a condition

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to retrieve the subcode and usn of students whose avg is less than 0.8. 
I tried something like this but it didnt work.

```
SELECT schedule.subcode,attendance.usn,   
FROM schedule,attendance 
where schedule.sched_id=attendance.sched_id  
having avg(attendance.ispresent)<0.8
group by attendance.usn
order by attendance.usn;
```

how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are asking, but the first thing I notice is that your having clause needs to come after your group by, and the subcode needs to be included in the group by statement. Also, use an inner join instead of the commas. Try this:

```
SELECT schedule.subcode, attendance.usn
FROM schedule
INNER JOIN attendance 
ON schedule.sched_id=attendance.sched_id  
GROUP BY schedule.subcode, attendance.usn
HAVING avg(attendance.ispresent)<0.8
ORDER BY attendance.usn;
```

Comment: @kbbali , thank you i am getting the desired output by the query you gave